# How to scrape multiple pages trouble with loop?

Tags: python, pandas, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here is my code to scrape only one page but I have 11000 of them. The difference is in their id.

```
https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_1.htm
https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_2.htm
https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_3.htm
....
https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_11000.htm
```

How can I loop my code to scrape all that 11000 pages? is it even possible  with such a big amount of pages ? It is possible to put them into a list and then scrape but with 11000 of them it will be a long way.

```
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_sc = requests.get('https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_1.htm')
soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]
mkb_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'first': mkb_names_sc,
    })
mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/MKB/mkb.csv')
```

Comment: Simply, pass the loop counter to the url: `'https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_{}.htm'.format(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the url strings on the fly like this. You may want to also use a timing delay in every other iteration of the loop to not be blocked by the server.

```
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


path_of_csv = '/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/MKB/mkb.csv'

first_string = 'https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_'
third_string = '.htm'

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['scraping results'])

try:
    for second_string in range(1, 11001):
        second_string = str(second_string)
        url = first_string + second_string + third_string
        page_sc = requests.get(url)
        soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
        items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
        mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]
        df.append({'scraping results': mkb_names_sc}, ignore_index=True)

    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=path_of_csv
    )

except:
    # If it fails in the middle of the process, the results won't be lost
    path_of_csv = 'backup_' + path_of_csv
    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=path_of_csv 
    )
    print('Failed at index ' + second_string + '. Please start from here again by setting the beginning of the range to this index. A backup was made of the results that were already scraped. You may want to rename the backup to avoid overwriting in the next run.')
```

Comment: This way, you avoid creating a long list prior to scraping. The issue of sending a lot of requests still remains, of course. You may want to refer to this question for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169900/python-web-scraping-difference-between-sleep-and-requestpage-timeout-x

Comment: both methods work good for me they do their job but for some reasons it overwrites data in my csv. How to avoid overwriting data?

Comment: Do you want to save the data to disk after every call? You also save the results to a pandas DataFrame (or list/array) and only save to csv at the very end. Updating a csv 11'000 times will take some time and is no good idea anyway. I would suggest the following solution: You create a list with results (result_list = []) and put the mkb_names_sc object in your list after every call/iteration (result_list.append(mkb_names_sc). In addition to that, you can use an error catcher that makes sure that your data isn't lost if something goes wrong. I'll update my answer soon to make this more clear.

Comment: Yes it saves data into a DataFrame I can see all the output in PyCharm, but not in my csv. I was also thinking to create a loop for csv's as well so for each page it will store data into a separate csv. but I think this will take me a whole day to first read all 11000 pages and them store them into all csv's. Also not all pages have the similar structure. So it doest define them all.  okay I will wait for you. thank you a lot.

Comment: yes it works with the loop but I think 11000 pages will be too much to store and then to understand them all

Comment: I've added some logic to the answer that backups intermediate results in case of an error. You can then presume from the index where you left off (just follow the instructions from the error message). When I ran this scraper, it failed after four url calls. Also, no output could be fetched from the website. Maybe you need some adjustments to the selectors that you use.

Comment: okay that is better then I did thank I a lot with this I hope I will finish my problem thank u lot I really appreciate that

Comment: You're welcome. Glad if it helps. Let me know if there are further issues with finding the correct selectors.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is very simple. I am just looping through the above code.

```py
for i in range(1,11001):

    page_sc = requests.get('https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_{}.htm'.format(i))

    soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
    items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
    mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]
    mkb_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'first': mkb_names_sc,
        })
    mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/MKB/mkb.csv')
```

What I have done is that I looped through code using the for loop and the `range()` function is generating the list of `index` which I placed in the url using the `format()` method.

And this should work like a charm. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You made my day man appreciate this. I just realized that not all my data from cite is scraping only those that have the same structure. But I think I will create just multiple of loops for each scenarios for each page struction